# Error after second spec run with rspec and autospec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest

After installing rspec/ZenTest and running autospec, it runs my specs the first time as expected. After making a change to one of my specs and upon running the second time I get the following results:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec --autospec /home/schambers/Projects/notebook/spec/models/user_spec.rb -O spec/spec.opts 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/formatter/progress_bar_formatter.rb:17:in `flush': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/formatter/progress_bar_formatter.rb:17:in `example_passed'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:136:in `example_passed'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:136:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:136:in `example_passed'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/reporter.rb:31:in `example_finished'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_methods.rb:55:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:214:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:212:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:212:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/example/example_group_methods.rb:103:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:22:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:152:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/bin/spec:5
```

Has anyone run into this or know what the heck is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Progress Bar is trying to print stuff to TTY so that it can show you your pretty spec progress output while it's running your tests.  I am guessing forking the process using autospec inherits STDOUT file descriptor, but can't write to it, so it throws the pipe error.

Try removing progress bar from RSpec helper.  Alternatively, try re-initializing progress bar plugin after fork.